# Expectation Random Variables

Tags: random-variables, expectation

Say $X$ to be uniformly distributed from $[0,1]$. Say $k_1$ and $k_2$ to be two non negative constants (that is, they take values from $[0,+inft]$.

I want to compute the expectation of the following max involving the two constants:

$$E[\max(X+k_1,k_2)]$$

(that is, the expectation of the max between the sum "random variable plus a constant k1" and "a constant k2").

As someone suggested:

let $Y=X+k_1$ be the uniform variable on $[k_1,k_1+1]$. Then your variable is $\max \{ Y,k_2 \}$. Cases:

- If $k_2 < k_1$, then $\max \{ Y,k_2 \} = Y$, so you have $E(Y)=\frac{2k_1+1}{2}$.
- If $k_2 > k_1+1$, then $\max \{ Y,k_2 \}=k_2$, so you have just $k_2$.
- If $k_1 \leq k_2 \leq k_1+1$, then $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq k_2) = k_2-k_1$.

how to handle the last case?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What calculations do you wish to pursue after stating what you know? What does $E[k2\mid X \leq k2-k1]$ mean since you have declared $k2$ to be a constant? How is its _expected_ value dependent on what $X$ is?

Comment: I edited the question.. now it is more clear? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=X+k_1$ be the uniform variable on $[k_1,k_1+1]$. Then your variable is $\max \{ Y,k_2 \}$. Cases:

- If $k_2 < k_1$, then $\max \{ Y,k_2 \} = Y$, so you have $E(Y)=\frac{2k_1+1}{2}$.
- If $k_2 > k_1+1$, then $\max \{ Y,k_2 \}=k_2$, so you have just $k_2$.
- If $k_1 \leq k_2 \leq k_1+1$, then $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq k_2) = k_2-k_1$.

Can you handle the last case?

Comment: suppose that k1,k2 are both non negatives (hence, they take values from [0,+inft]

Comment: I do not get which should be the last case to be still handled!

Comment: I'll be a bit more careful. I'll write $Z=\max \{ Y,k_2 \}$. Then $E(Z) = E(Z|Y \leq k_2) P(Y \leq k_2) + E(Z|Y > k_2) P(Y>k_2)$, using the total expectation formula. The first term is just $k_2 P(Y \leq k_2) = k_2 (k_2 - k_1)$. How can you compute the second term?

Comment: Ok now I understood. Sorry.

So it is:

$E[Z|Y>k_{2}]P(Y>k_{2})=\frac{k_{1}+k_{1}+1}{2}*[(k_{1}+1)-k2]$

correct?

Comment: Not quite. You have $P(Y>k_2)$ correct, but you don't have $E(Z|Y>k_2)$ correct. What you wrote is the expected value of $Y$, but when you know $Y>k_2$, the expected value increases. Note that if $Y>k_2$ then $Z=Y$, so you need to find the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $Y>k_2$. You should find that it is the uniform distribution on $[k_2,k_1+1]$ (rather than $[k_1,k_1+1]$).

Comment: $E[Z|Y>k_{2}]P(Y>k_{2})=\frac{k_{2}+k_{1}+1}{2}*[(k_{1}+1)-k2]$

Now It is done.

Comment: @Johan Indeed. Do you see why $(Z|Y>k_2)$ has the distribution I claimed?

Comment: I think yes. Because given $Y>k_{2}$ then $Z|Y>k_{2}$ is uniform in $[k_{2},k_{1}+1]$ and then the expected value of $Z|Y>k_{2}$ is the mean between these extremes.

Comment: That's intuitively correct. Strictly speaking you should use the formula for the conditional density.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> Note that $\ds{\max\pars{a,b} = {a + b + \verts{a - b} \over 2}}$. Then,

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large{\mathbb E}\bracks{\max\pars{X + k_{1},k_{2}}}}
={\mathbb E}\bracks{X + k_{1} + k_{2} + \verts{X + k_{1} - k_{2}} \over 2}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 4} + {k_{1} + k_{2} \over 2}
+\half\,\color{#c00000}{{\mathbb E}\pars{\verts{X + k_{1} - k_{2}}}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{{\mathbb E}\bracks{\verts{X + k_{1} - k_{2}}}}
> =\int_{0}^{1}\verts{X + k_{1} - k_{2}}\,\dd X
> \\[5mm]&=\verts{1 + k_{1} - k_{2}}
> -\int_{0}^{1}X\sgn\pars{X + k_{1} - k_{2}}\,\dd X
> \\[5mm]&=\verts{1 + k_{1} - k_{2}} - \half\,\sgn\pars{1 + k_{1} - k_{2}}
> + \int_{0}^{1}X^{2}\,\delta\pars{X + k_{1} - k_{2}}\,\dd X 
> \\[5mm]&=\verts{1 + k_{1} - k_{2}} - \half\,\sgn\pars{1 + k_{1} - k_{2}}
> + \pars{k_{2} - k_{1}}^{2}
> \int_{0}^{1}\delta\pars{X - \bracks{k_{2} - k_{1}}}\,\dd X 
> \\[5mm]&=\color{#c00000}{%
> \verts{1 + k_{1} - k_{2}} - \half\,\sgn\pars{1 + k_{1} - k_{2}}
> + \pars{k_{2} - k_{1}}^{2}\Theta\pars{k_{2} - k_{1}}\Theta\pars{1 - k_{2} + k_{1}}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large{\mathbb E}\bracks{\max\pars{X + k_{1},k_{2}}}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 4} + {k_{1} + k_{2} \over 2}
+\half\,\verts{1 + k_{1} - k_{2}} - {1 \over 4}\,\sgn\pars{1 + k_{1} - k_{2}}}
\\[5mm]&+ \color{#66f}{\large\half\,\pars{k_{2} - k_{1}}^{2}
\Theta\pars{k_{2} - k_{1}}\Theta\pars{1 - k_{2} + k_{1}}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\delta\pars{x}}$ is the
>   [Dirac Delta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) and $\ds{\Theta\pars{x}}$ is the
>   [Heaviside Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) .